# iOS swift testing version 1.2 errors,

Tags: ios, swift

original code

```
  // add a tap gesture recognizer
  let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
  let gestureRecognizers = NSMutableArray()
  gestureRecognizers.addObject(tapGesture)
  if let existingGestureRecognizers = sceneView.gestureRecognizers {
    gestureRecognizers.addObjectsFromArray(existingGestureRecognizers)
  }
  sceneView.gestureRecognizers = gestureRecognizers

error -->> sceneView.gestureRecognizers = gestureRecognizers
```

unfortunately updated to latest version of swift 1.2

```
'NSMutableArray' is not convertible to '[AnyObject]'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?
```

it wants to change the line to

```
sceneView.gestureRecognizers = gestureRecognizers as! [AnyObject]
```

and after changing accepting, I now get this error

```
Cannot assign a value of type '[AnyObject]' to a value of type '[AnyObject]?'
```

the swift migrator was no help, neither are the release notes.

this is not my code as i didn't want to screw up my own repo so this a project from github.

https://github.com/ryanshelby/Stonehenge

thanks for any help

Comment: May I ask why you ever entered the NSMutableArray world in the first place?

Comment: That last error is confusing, a property of `[AnyObject]?` should accept `[AnyObject]`.  You should be able to do a `as?` cast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Swift migrator is wrong in this case.  Swift 1.2 does not support implicit casting from `NSArray` to `[AnyObject]` anymore so it correctly determined that a cast to `[AnyObject]` was required but it incorrectly added it as an unsafe cast rather than a safe one.  I'm assuming the unsafe cast is not valid code and should generate an error, but the message it's displaying is not correct.

The following line should give the desired result but matt is right that you probably want to rework your code to avoid `NSMutableArray`:

```
sceneView.gestureRecognizers = gestureRecognizers as [AnyObject]
```

A concise way to avoid this would be to grab the original array or create a new one, insert the item, and reassign.

```
var gestureRecognizers = screenView.gestureRecognizers ?? []
gestureRecognizers.insert(tapGesture, atIndex: 0)
screenView.gestureRecognizers = gestureRecognizers
```

That said, `UIView` already has an API for adding a single gesture recognizer:

```
screenView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Comment: Your formulation is better than mine.

Comment: Thanks, marked this as answer.  As a caveat, if you run the swift migrator and you get these errors, you're hosed until you fix the code.  The migrator even changes the default AppDelegate file.  I tried the it on other sample code and it failed as well with errors like this one.  I won't be updating swift versions yet.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but your code was nutty to start with:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
let gestureRecognizers = NSMutableArray()
gestureRecognizers.addObject(tapGesture)
if let existingGestureRecognizers = sceneView.gestureRecognizers {
    gestureRecognizers.addObjectsFromArray(existingGestureRecognizers)
}
sceneView.gestureRecognizers = gestureRecognizers
```

What are you trying to do? If you want an array containing this gesture recognizer, just make it:

```
var gestureRecognizers = 
    [UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")]
```

If you then want to append the objects in the existing gesture recognizers, just append them:

```
gestureRecognizers.extend(existingGestureRecognizers)
```

By simplifying and rationalizing in this way, I think you'll solve your other difficulties.